# Rest API for breakroleinheritance gives UnAuthorized Error

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, custom-list

I've created workflow for breaking inheritance rule of list item. I am using breakroleinheritance command to break the role using Rest API call by workflow. After breaking the rule, I am assigning new role to list item.
Here is the code for Rest API:

```
https://my-websiteurl.com/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Course Material')/getItemByID(1)/breakroleinheritance(copyRoleAssignments=true,clearSubscopes=true)
```

I've passed header also:

```
Accept : application/json;odata=verbose
Content-Type : application/json;odata=verbose
X-RequestDigest : digestValue
```

I am getting digestValue properly by calling RestAPI correct.
When I call above API, I am getting UnAuthorized response in Log.

Reference Site : http://blog.appliedis.com/2014/10/09/sharepoint-designer-2013-workflow-working-with-web-services/

Note: Above code is working well with http, I am trying with https. I am also working with sharepoint designer 2013

Answer (score 1):

Go to **Site Settings** - > **Manage site features** ->Activate "**Workflows can use app permissions" and all the call to REST endpoint within the app step"**.

Refer the following url's for the actual steps:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj822159.aspx

http://summit7systems.com/app-step-or-impersonation-step-in-sharepoint-designer-2013/